# Storing a JSON string in SQL Server and returning with ASP.NET Web API and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a SQL Server (2012) database schema which is somewhat similar to that of a Shopping Website or Social website in that there are multiple 'items' that each have multiple images, although for each image I store about 10 different sizes of that image.

My plan was to have one table to hold all image data, one row for each original image eg. with column names of:

```
ImageID
PostID (foreign key)
OriginalImageWidth
OriginalImageHeight
OriginalImageFileUrl
ImageSizesJSON (nvarchar(MAX))
```

The last column `ImageSizesJSON` would store an array of JSON objects representing the various (auto-sized-on-upload) resized images for that item. For example like:

```
[{ "height": 1536, "width": 2048, "source": "images/post/1/2048x1536.jpg" },
{ "height": 960, "width": 720, "source": "images/post/1/960x720.jpg" },
{ "height": 720, "width": 540, "source": "images/post/1/720x540.jpg" }]
```

This is particularly to avoid all of the following:

1. excessive database calls/table joins (as won't need to query the various sizes) - ie. denormalising the database for the original-image to image-sizes data
2. unnecessary reading of the file system for all image sizes, and
   the associated disconnection of (meta)data storage locations (DB and Filesystem)
3. unnecessary application code to handle the various image sizes (all that needs to be done to handle all image sizes can be done on upload and in a batch script (including serialising the image size array to JSON and saving it to the DB)).

I am using .NET (4.5), the Entity Framework (most recent - 5.0 I believe (numbering is confusing)) and the Web API to return JSON AJAX web services to my web based and mobile app.

However, I am having problems combining the JSON returned from the SQL Server column 'ImageSizesJSON' with the JSON output by the Web API after/during serialisation of my POCO.

I've tried various ways to combine them but each has issues I can't surmount, and I'm not sure which is the best way either:

1. Simply treating the column as a CLR `string`. The problem with this method is that when the JSON is returned by the webservice, the JSON is treated (as expected) as a string, and double quotes are escaped, the whole JSON has quotes around it etc., and I can't find a way to have it output as pure JSON, and am unsure of any other way to get around the way it is output. Maybe this can be handled suitably in JavaScript though..?
2. Serialising the JSON back to the POCO object, and then 'appending' it to my LINQ to EF query for the Web API to then reserialise for output as JSON (even though I realise this is an unnecessary double overhead). When I try to do this, I get various errors appending the serialised JSON in the LINQ to EF query, such as 'this method cannot be translated into a store expression' or 'Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.' I understand why these errors occur but I am unsure how to get around them (elegantly) either.

After a lot of Googling I am almost at the point of giving up the denormalised image-size table schema for the moment just to progress at this point, however the approach seems like the best app architecture to me and I'd like to know how to do it (plus I think other people would find it handy too), so I'd greatly appreciate pointers towards a solution or ideally code to handle either of the problems I've mentioned.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem, using option #1 (treating the column holding the JSON string as a .NET `string` type). In the JavaScript/AJAX that calls the Web API webservices, all I needed to do was reference the `ImageSizesJSON` column using `JSON.parse()` eg:

```
var imagesJson = JSON.parse(ImageSizesJSON);
```

This converts the escape string of JSON to a JSON object, so that it can be worked with correctly as an object in JavaScript.